# Azure Create Pull Request API throwing error: "Invalid argument value.Both a source and target reference is required."

Tags: powershell, azure-api-apps

I am new to using Azure APIs to create an automation script to do the merge of ReleaseCandidate to master post production release.
For that I am trying to create a pull request using the Azure REST APIs. but facing the below error:
Invoke-WebRequest : {"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"Invalid argument value.\r\nParameter name: Both a source and target reference is required.

My request body is like below:

```
$requestBody = @{
  targetRefName = "refs/heads/master";
  sourceRefName = "refs/heads/release/Release-2.42.0";
  reviewers = "77c0ffe29d3169a58ca0737bc05b76f9";
  title = "post release merge to master"
}

Request:
$AzurePRUrl = "https://dev.azure.com/{organisation}/_apis/git/repositories/{$RepositoryId}/pullrequests?api-version=5.0"  
$AzureCreatePRResult = $(Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $AzurePRUrl -UseBasicParsing -ContentType 'application/json' -Headers $Headers -Method post -Body $requestBody | ConvertTo-Json).content
```

No information on documentation or anywhere else related to this type of error. I am stuck at the moment. Please suggest.

Comment: Do you have any other concerns? If you have no other concerns, could you please [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)? It may help more persons。

Answer (score 0):

According to my test, the reviewers should a list of objects. For more details, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull%20requests/create?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0#request-body). So please update  `$requestBody` as `@{ targetRefName = "refs/heads/master"; sourceRefName = "refs/heads/release/Release-2.42.0"; reviewers =@{ "id"="77c0ffe29d3169a58ca0737bc05b76f9"}; title = "post release merge to master" }`.

For example

```
$requestBody = @{
  targetRefName = "refs/heads/master";
  sourceRefName = "refs/heads/test1";
  reviewers = @{"id"="d33731c1-c059-6d48-9408-be0e725276f4"};
  title = "post powershell script to test"
} | ConvertTo-Json
$AzurePRUrl = "https://dev.azure.com/{organisation}/_apis/git/repositories/{$RepositoryId}/pullrequests?api-version=5.1"  


$result=(Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing -Uri $url -Headers $headers -ContentType "application/json" -Method Post -Body $requestBody) 
$result.Content
```

[image]